# 6 dots & 5 slopes

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, graph-theory, slope

I read this question somewhere:

> Is it possible to mark 6 dots on a surface, and connect them two by two to make lines, in which the total number of slopes is 5 ?

There is also the same question but with different numbers. They were easier to solve than this one:

$4$ dots & $4$ slopes
[image]

$5$ dots & $4$ slopes
[image]

I don't know if I said that correctly, but my point is that if you count all parallel lines as one line, you will have 5 lines in total.

I want to know if possible, how and if not, how can we prove that it's impossible.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You'll get a lot more help if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself, even if you haven't made much progress. What are your thoughts? What have you tried? How far could you get? Where are you stuck? This question will likely be closed if you don't add more context. Please respond by editing the question body. Clarifications don't belong in the comments.

Comment: @saulspatz Thanks for your advice, I added some information. I hope that's enough.

Comment: Yes, that's fine. +1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible: Any $6$ non-collinear points determine at least $6$ different slopes.

More generally, for $n\geq 4$ non-collinear points the minimum number of slopes is

- $n-1$, if $n$ is odd
- $n$, if $n$ is even.

See [P. Ungar: $2N$ Noncollinear points determine at least $2N$ directions](https://doi.org/10.1016/0097-3165(82)90045-0)